# Use shortcode within definition of shortcode

Tags: hugo, hugo-shortcode

How can I reuse a shortcode in Hugo within another shortcode?

I only found a way to nest shortcodes within markdown but what I want to do is to reuse a shortcode within the definition of another shortcode.

Answer (score 6):

No not in the definition, but you can use nested Shortcodes.

The nested approach is the official one (as [discussed here](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/programmatically-use-shortcode-inside-another-shortcodes-definition-file/11580/10)):

> ### [Nested Shortcodes](https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/#nested-shortcodes)
>
> You can call shortcodes within other shortcodes by creating your own templates that leverage the `.Parent` variable.
> `.Parent` allows you to check the context in which the shortcode is being called.
> See [Shortcode templates](https://gohugo.io/templates/shortcode-templates/).

See an [illustration here](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/solved-can-i-check-if-a-shortcode-is-inside-another-shortcode/5811): this is a workaround, and not *one* shortcode using another.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with partials as a workaround: You can outsource your reusable shortcode into a partial and call that inside your shortcode as often as you want. For the sake of an example, I'm going to write my own *string to lowercase* function:

`layout/partials/string-to-lower.html`:

```
{{- $stringOriginal := . -}}
{{- $stringLower := $stringOriginal | lower -}}
{{- return $stringLower -}}
```

`layout/shortcodes/some-shortcode.html`:

```
{{- $myString := "TeST" -}}
{{- partial "string-to-lower" $myString -}}
```

`{{< some-shortcode >}}` will then print `test` in your content.

---

If you want to use your shortcode not only in other shortcodes, but also in your content, then you can work with a wrapper shortcode for your outsourced shortcode (partial):

`layout/partials/string-to-lower.html` (the outsourced code):

```
{{- $stringOriginal := . -}}
{{- $stringLower := $stringOriginal | lower -}}
{{- return $stringLower -}}
```

`layout/shortcodes/string-to-lower.html` (the wrapper):

```
{{- with .Get 0 -}}
    {{- partial "string-to-lower" . -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Then you can use `{{< string-to-lower "TeST" >}}` in your content or `{{- partial "string-to-lower" "TeST" -}}` in your templates to print `test`.